# Cannot target the JSON object without undefined result

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, object

I have JSON encoded data which is pulled through ajax, i am trying to access the data through jQuery and populate some fields, however for some reason i keep getting error `data.entry_data is undefined`

JSON Data Structure:

```
{
   "activity_counts":null,
   "config":{
      "csrf_token":"56gdf75fd6756g7",
      "viewer":null
   },
   "supports_es6":false,
   "country_code":"NL",
   "language_code":"en",
   "locale":"en_US",
   "entry_data":{
      "ProfileData":[
         {
            "logging_page_id":"profilePage_2321",
            "show_suggested_profiles":false,
            "userspecific":{
               "user":{
                  "full_name":"John Doe",
                  "username":"JohnDoe1",
                  "country":"United States"
               }
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

My jQuery Code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "engine.php",
    data: $("#profile-info-form").serialize(),
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
        $profile_full_name = data.entry_data.ProfileData.userspecific.user.full_name;
        $profile_country = data.entry_data.ProfileData.userspecific.user.country;
        $profile_username = data.entry_data.ProfileData.userspecific.user.username;
    },
    error: function(){
        profileError();
    }
});
```

I also tried using `data[0]` for example `$profile_full_name = data[0].entry_data.ProfileData.userspecific.user.full_name;` without any success, as it is showing same undefined error.

I am bugging my head for days now trying to figure out what am i doing wrong when targeting the JSON object, any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If the data returned in success callback is really the JSON structure pasted above, then `data.entry_data` should not be undefined. There should be no problem with it.

The problem lies in accessing `userspecific` property since `ProfileData` is an array.

Try changing this part: `data.entry_data.ProfileData.userspecific` to `data.entry_data.ProfileData[0].userspecific`.

See this fiddle for an example : https://jsfiddle.net/mom5gw2q/7/